# defining a view resolver in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am creating a new project based on 3.1 M1 as a test case. I have my web.xml set up to use DispatcherServlet with a contextClass of org.springframework.web.context.support.Annotation ConfigWebApplicationContext and a contextConfigLocation of domain.ApplicationConfiguration.

However, when a method from one of my @Controller annotated classes with attempts to return a ModelAndView with a view name of "test" I it looks for a method in the same controller class with a @RequestMapping of "test" when I would like it to look for a jsp named "test.jsp" in the WebContent directory, and it looks like no viewresolver is never instantiated. I have tried declaring a view resolver in the ApplicationConfiguration class but it seems to be ignored.
I always get a log message something like:
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/test/foo/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

How do I configure a view resolver in 3.1?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<context-param>
<param-name>contextClass</param-name>
<param-value>
org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>domain.test.configuration.ApplicationConfiguration</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextClass</param-name>
<param-value>
org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>domain.test</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What other pieces of configuration would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-resolver), the usual way of defining a JSP viewResolver is:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: That would require creating a servletName.xml file, which is no longer required in 3.1.  You are supposed to be able to do all configuration with annotations where the only xml file that is required is the web.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

It started working when I changed the  tag from:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

to:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

I know that servlet 3.0 support was due in Milestone 2, I just didn't expect that kind of failure mode for preemptively declaring it.  I got no errors, it just ignored all of my Controller mappings.

Comment: Add this to your initial question, you can edit your question. This should not be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Do not give the Url Pattern as `/*`. Mention the Url Pattern as `*.htm`. Surely it will work.